# Java Concurrent API's

Tags: java

Can some one please explain how **CAS(compare swap)** machine instructions are leveraged by **java concurrent API's**?

Comment: No I have been graduated from school :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAS instructions are used in the [Atomic*](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_7_atomic.shtml) classes.
For why you would want to use them vs `volatile`, [see here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_when.shtml).